# Highcharts javascript

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Am using highcharts scatter plots. I wanted to give a glow effect to a point on selecting the point. So am using chart.renderer.rect() method to create a SVG element and add it behind the selected point. But i am not getting the x y position of the selected point. Please help me.

Below is the code am using.

```
chart.renderer.rect( 1, 1, 30, 30, 5)
 .attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        stroke: 'red',
        fill: 'yellow',
        zIndex: 3,
        translateX: 220,
        translateY: 265
 })
 .add();
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

See the following example.
http://jsfiddle.net/cfKzS/7/
If you want the chart x and y position you can access as this.x and this.y.
Or if you want the position in pixels you can use something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
            events: {
                select: function(e) {
                    $report.html('chart x position: ' + e.target.plotX + '<br>' + 'chart y position: ' + e.target.plotY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform is not part of the attr object see here... 
http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#element

```
attr Object hash : Element Since 2.0
Apply attributes to the SVG/VML elements. These attributes for the most parts correspond to SVG, but some are specific to Highcharts, like zIndex and rotation for text.

Most important available attributes:

d
end
fill
height
r
rotation
start
stroke
stroke-width
style
text
translateX
translateY
visibility
width
x
y
zIndex
```

Comment: i tried with translateX, translateY. It displays the rectangle. but the position is not at the proper place. point.x and point.y are the graph points. but i need the x y position of a point in a container

Comment: i suggest you place your code on to jsfiddle so that people can see the rest of your code and attempt to fix it